# main.CRITICAL: Table "catalogrule_product_replica" does not exist Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I have been getting this in my logs and phpmyadmin

main.CRITICAL: Table "catalogrule_product_replica" does not exist

when I try to run these 2 indexes they are failing
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product

Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.

I have tried to drop the table and import from backup working database however it still does not reindex. But the error does go away

Any help would be most appreicated as I am stuck for 2 days

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please copy this table :

> catalogrule_product_replica

From any other magento 2 project database and create it on your current database.Then Run this command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

It will be solved!